# What is the situation with Intel Poulsbo drivers on Ubuntu (e.g. X11 windows) now?

Tags: xorg, gpu-driver, poulsbo

I know about the GMA500 driver, but I can't compile the source code. Is there any chance to find working Poulsbo GPUs driver for the latest Ubuntu distro? I just need GLX so I can watch movies on this laptop sometimes.. Thanks..

Comment: Please edit your question and include more details. You should explain the steps you have taken so far and give clear details about the actual problem you are facing. Include commands, output and all error messages (complete and verbatim) so that we can understand the problem.

Comment: I doubt it.  The hardware is old and unsupported by both Intel and Imagination. The best you can do is wrap it as a gift, and send to Intel with a f@#k you note.